# MFC 7.0 C++ How to get a CBitmap from CImage

Tags: c++, mfc

I like to know how to get a `CBitmap` from `CImage` in MFC code.

The problem is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bwea7by5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) tells me to use `CImage::m_hBitmap` to generate a `CBitmap` from handle. But unfortunately `CImage::m_hBitmap` is private to `CImage`. Do I get something wrong?

Code excerpt from MSDN:

```
CImage image;
// Code to create load/create image goes here
// ...
CBitmap* pBitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle(image.m_hBitmap);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the handle from `m_hBitmap` use the `CImage` object directly. The online help at MSDN seems not updated correctly.

The MFC developer(s) has added an operator `HBITMAP`, so conversion from `CImage` to `HBITMAP` works without user intervention.

The inline code that gives access to `m_hBitmap` in header `atlimage.h`:

```
inline CImage::operator HBITMAP() const throw()
{
  return (m_hBitmap);
}
```

In order to have a working code `image.m_hBitmap` must be replaced with `image` only.

```
CImage image;
// Code to create load/create image goes here
// ...
CBitmap* pBitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle(image);
```

That's it.

**EDIT**: I've found an alternative solution too, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490661/how-to-load-png-jpeg-images-using-mfc).