# MFC how to convert PNG with transparent attribute to HBITMAP

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I loaded `PNG` file using GDI+.

My source use `HBITMAP` so I convert `PNG` to `HBITMAP`.

`PNG` file has a transparent background but `HBITMAP` has a background.

I want to remove backround from `HBITMAP`.

Comment: Have you looked into the `CImage` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class ?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle i tried `CImage::TransparentBlt` but i want to be convered to `HBITMAP` with transparent background

Comment: So you can't just load it, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490661/how-to-load-png-jpeg-images-using-mfc ? The `CImage` class works with transparency. You should be able to display transparent images. Others might be able to help you more but i think you might have to provide more context and some sample code of what you are currently doing. Plus example of what the current results are.

Comment: The `CImage` class implements [`operator HBITMAP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class#operator_hbitmap), so you can easily pass a `CImage` anywhere an `HBITMAP` is expected. Note that alpha transparency is not a property that's stored with an `HBITMAP`. An alpha channel is implied depending on the API you use (e.g. [AlphaBlend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351.aspx) vs. [StretchBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120.aspx)).

Comment: What kind of PNG file is it? There are two kinds, 8-bit palette with transparent colors (like a GIF) and 32-bit with alpha transparency.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I have to use `HBITMAP` so  I did not use `CImage` and used `GdipCreateBitmapFromStream`, `GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap`. so if i use `CImage`, I can use `PNG` as `HBITMAP` with transparent background ?

Comment: @IInspectable so if i use `CImage` and `AlphaBlend` , i can use it as `HBITMAP` with transparency?

Comment: @MarkRansom 32bit with alpha transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have enough information. This is how I load transparent PNG files:

```
// Based on afxbutton.cpp's static function ButtonLoadBitmap
HBITMAP __stdcall CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::ButtonLoadBitmap(UINT uiBmpResId)
{
    if (uiBmpResId == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    LPCTSTR lpszResourceName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(uiBmpResId);
    ENSURE(lpszResourceName != nullptr);

    HBITMAP hbmp = nullptr;

    // Try to load PNG image first:
    CPngImage pngImage;
    if (pngImage.Load(lpszResourceName))
    {
        hbmp = (HBITMAP)pngImage.Detach();
    }
    else
    {
        HINSTANCE hinstRes = AfxFindResourceHandle(lpszResourceName, RT_BITMAP);
        if (hinstRes == nullptr)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        UINT uiLoadImageFlags = LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS;

        hbmp = (HBITMAP) ::LoadImage(hinstRes, lpszResourceName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, uiLoadImageFlags);
    }

    return hbmp;
}
```

My code is designed to load a resource but you can adjust it to work with external files.

Comment: Your `PNG` image come out clean without using `GDI+` ?

Comment: My `PNG` image is 32bit with alpha channel so when i use your code, loaded broken image

Comment: @Davidseong CPngImage is called first. That caters for transparent images.